# Sum numbers in one column

Tags: excel, sum, multiplication

I've a Excel spreadsheet and there's summation and multiplication in my last result a have a big number like this

```
482362534
```

and what i want to sum this number for example

```
4+8+2+3+6+2+5+3+4
```

and show me the result 37 in another column, is there's a function to do this ?

Comment: Treat it as a string and get char by char, then sum those digits. I doubt that there is similar function out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it as,

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))
```